# Wordpress responsive menu not dropping down

Tags: wordpress

Cheers,
My responsive website just shows the word Menu for the navigation on mobile. When you click it's supposed to show the primary navigation, and it did for years. I just noticed it does not work anymore and I'm not familiar with responsive code.

MacInspires.com

based on Twenty Eleven Theme
Wordpress

Thank you for any assistance or point in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done via Javascript. Disable the minification, compression/optiomization plugins you’re using. They may be breaking the javascript used to manage that menu.

This may be a plugin or theme conflict. Please attempt to disable all plugins. If the problem goes away, enable them one by one to identify the source of your troubles.

If you can install plugins, install “Health Check” (https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check). On the troubleshooting tab, you can click the button to disable all plugins and change the theme for you, while you’re still logged in, without affecting normal visitors to your site. This may be a faster option. Let me know how things go and I will try to help further if required.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for your response and amazing hair.
I used Health Check to disable all plugins and the menu on mobile still does not work :(

Comment: Haha, thanks. Has the menu been created by yourself or by your theme?

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy Fixed it!
site had a mixed content issue, where resources were being pulled both from HTTP and HTTPS sources. I have installed and activated the plugin Really Simple SSL. This resolved the mixed content issue, and also the mobile menu issue.